# libphonenumber-js validate on input

Tags: javascript, html, input, formatting, format

I'm using this library to format the phone input like this
input: xxxxxxxxxxx
formatter returns: xxxx xxx xx xx

What i want and is not avaliable in the documentation is to prevent writing in the input when the phone number is full.

Example: the number above is 9 charecter length, i don't need the user to be able to write more than that

Code to format input:

```
telInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    const formatter = new AsYouType(isoCode2)
    telInput.value = formatter.input(telInput.value)
})
```

> Note: the phone number lenght is changeable based on another select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by setting a new maxlength when ever the phone is changes(idea by [avva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19963522/avaa))

```
const template = formatter.formatter.template || 'xxxxxxxxxx'
const newLength = template.length.toString()
telInput.setAttribute('maxlength', newLength)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically prevent user from typing in keypress. sth like this:

```
telInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if(telInput.value.length>maxLength){
    e.preventDefault()
    }
})
```

Comment: As i mentioned above the phone number is changeable and the length to so this well not work

Comment: i missed the quotation part of your answer i edited my answer.

Comment: Steel not fix it, when user changes the country it's has a deffrent phone length.  
Anyway I'v found the answer inspired by your, I'll post it soon.  
Thanks for you help